# What's the meaning of numbers in numpy arrays?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

In `numpy`, The `array` method could convert a image to a big array, the question is , whats' the meaning of the numbers in this array?(RGB value? gray-scale value? )

What's more, when I convert a image to mode"1", tried

```
im = Image.open("test.jpg")
# Some processing ...
im = im.convert("1")
im_arr = array(im,dtype=uint8)
```

I found that the im_arr array shows not only 0 and 255:

```
array([[170, 170, 170, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 248, 255, ..., 175, 255, 222],
       [255, 255, 247, ..., 175, 170, 171],
       ..., 
       [ 32, 105, 110, ...,  32, 124,  32],
       [ 32,  32,  32, ..., 101, 115,  39],
       [ 41,  10,  32, ..., 109, 111, 115]], dtype=uint8)
```

Why? (I really want to know the meaning of numbers in array of different modes)

Comment: Where did you get `im` from initially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By running `im.convert("1")`, you are converting your loaded image into a bilevel image which *should* only have pixel values of 0 or 255.  To do this properly,

```
im_arr = np.array(im.getdata(), dtype = np.uint8).reshape(im.size[0], im.size[1])
```

With this, you will receive your desired bilevel image, which you could save or view with `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`.

The odd number you are receiving are coming from the conversion process to a numpy array.  If you choose different data types (`np.int`, `np.int8`, `np.uint8`, ...), you will find that each of these return a different array.

Without knowing much about the object structure of `PIL.Image`, I couldn't say why this is.  But I think it's safe to say that without `.getdata()` the results are garbage.

Answer (score 1):

The format jpeg does not support mode 1. Save it into a different format, png or bmp, and look at the array for that one instead.

[Documentation for PIL Jpeg](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/format-jpeg.htm)